# Displaying an object hierarchy within NSOutlineView - cannot get it to work correctly, any tips?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

So, I want to use NSOutlineView in my application to display a specific, for a lack of a better name, hierarchy. 
To explain, here's how it looks in the code:
I have a protocol that declares a few methods used by the objects I'd like to display:

```
@protocol OutlineViewItem <NSObject>

@required -(BOOL)hasChildren; //Tells whether the object has children
@required -(NSInteger)numberOfChildren; //returns 0 if none or number of children
@required -(id)getChildren; //return NSMutableArray containing children
@required -(NSString*)getDisplayableName; //returns a string that would be displayed in NSOutlineView

@end
```

As it can be guessed, these methods should make my task a little bit easier.

Then, I've got a following hierarchy of objects (all of them implement that protocol) ->

Main application contains one instance of a Project class, that contains a NSMutableArray of Subproject class instances, that contains a NSMutableArray of SubprojectItem class instances.

An example of how I'm using these protocol methods in Project class (subprojects is the aforementioned NSMutableArray:

```
-(BOOL)hasChildren{
    if(subprojects == nil || [subprojects count] < 1){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfChildren{
    if(subprojects == nil){
        return 0;
    }
    return [subprojects count];
}

-(id)getChildren{
    return subprojects;
}

-(NSString*)getDisplayableName{
    return name;
}
```

Subproject and SubprojectItem classes implement these methods in a similar way.

In my application, I've defined the main window class (ProjectWindow) to implement NSOutlineViewDataSource and Delegate protocols, and I've bound NSOutlineView's data source and delegate to ProjectWindow.

in ProjectWindowClass, I've implemented methods as follow:

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    return item == nil ? project : [item getChildren];
    //if I understand it correctly, it return the children of a given node.
    //if item is nil, it should return the root, that is, project, or the children of item.
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    return item == nil? YES : [item hasChildren];
    //Same as above: project is expendable, other nodes can be expanded if contain children    
}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
    return item == nil? 1 : [item numberOfChildren];
    //Same as above: there's 1 project, or it returns num of children;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
{
    return item == nil ? @"ROOT" : [item getDisplayableName];
    //I think that's what is going to be displayed in NSOutlineView, next to the expendable arrow
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I'm met with a following exception:

```
2013-08-23 22:45:12.930 myProject[1903:303] -[__NSArrayM hasChildren]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101a16f30
```

If I understood the whole NSOutlineViewDataSource, it should either return the root item, if requested with item == nil, of children of item if item != nil. But, although I've thought that it's how it should be, it doesn't work, and application hangs.

So, how should I implement all these data source methods to make it work as intended?

Comment: `getChildren` should just be named `children`, and why did you declare its return type as `id` rather than `NSArray *`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
> {
>     return item == nil ? project : [item getChildren];
>     //if I understand it correctly, it return the children of a given node.
> ```

Not all of them at once!

`outlineView:child:ofItem:` takes an index because it's expected to return the child at that index. It's supposed to return one child at a time.

You're telling the outline view that the array of all children of the project is every child of the project. I don't think that's what you meant.

You want:

```
return item == nil ? project : item[index];
```

(By the way, you should not name a variable `index`. There is a function by that name, so if you forget or misspell the variable's declaration, hilarity will ensue when you then use the `index` function as an array index.)

> ```
> - (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
> {
>     return item == nil ? @"ROOT" : [item getDisplayableName];
>     //I think that's what is going to be displayed in NSOutlineView, next to the expendable arrow
> ```

Yes, so you want a localized string. Use `NSLocalizedString` around the `@"ROOT"` string. Better yet, move that to a method in the project, and just ask for the item's displayable name unconditionally.